# Superpower: Making objects indestructible. Downsides, benefits, etc. Need advice

Tags: super-powers

I'm currently writing a story where superpowers exist. Each and every superpowered individual basically is a low-level reality warper, specifically tailored to their superpower.

One character I have in mind is someone who can turn objects indestructible. They still retain whatever other properties they've had before, ie. metals can still be bent, plastic is still lightweight, etc. They can affect up to car-sized things, or not exceeding a mass of 2 tons.

What I'm looking for advice is what sorts of feats can one do with this type of power? Currently, they are operating as an armorer/support hero for their team, providing really lightweight armor/weaponry that doesn't break, as well as mechanic for their near bulletproof vehicles

Comment: if things can still be bent its not very indestructible, crushing a soda can flat is just bending it after all. his armor is also useless, armor that can be bent does not make for good armor. Ditto for weapons a sword with a bend blade or a gun with a bent barrel is basically useless.

Comment: @John all materials have a yield point. Before that point any deformation will return to its original position. Ignoring microscopic damage from repeat bending you can easily assume this as the limit unless you want to nitpick. Also for armor you kinda want it to bend somewhat to absorb kinetic energy over time and reduce the sudden impact.

Comment: @Demigan that is called flexing, bending refers to either elastic or plastic deformation, although more often than not it refers to plastic deformation when applied to metal.

Comment: Since there's obvious disagreement about the parameters of the question because of unclear definitions (I'm not sure how it works either), I'm inclined to encourage the OP to provide further info. Voting to put on hold: needs details and clarity.

Comment: Can this hero transform regular objects instantaneously (ex. during a battle), or this process takes time and concentration?

Comment: Looking further into this, my original idea of this power follows more along the lines of having some flex/give but not to the point of permanent deformation. I.E. used on fabric the fabric would never tear but still can be folded about/crumpled without issue. My first idea of application this character would use is to reinforce their cosplay armor as actual armor when they gain their powers.

Comment: @Alexander they can instantaneously reinforce any object they touch. It is also permanent, until the hero hits that 2 ton limit of mass they've reinforced.

Comment: Does this work on people, or other living beings? Could they make *themselves* indestructible, for instance?

Comment: King Midas somehow strikes the bill... but he had Power Incontinence too...

Comment: @F1Krazy Only on objects, so no indestructible people.

Answer (score 2):

The smart thing for armored cars would be some elastic armor, several thin weaves of a cloth-like material or thin sheets of some other elastic material.

Early cars were made to be as strong as possible. When in an accident the cars had little damage, but the occupants were laminated across the inside of the car. That is why we now install crumple zones to absorb impacts and help save to occupants. Assuming the elasticity goes up to the yield point of a material you can use a cloth or sheet of an elastic material over the regular car metal. Bullets and even larger canon weaponry will get caught and more gradually be absorbed. For extra safety you do install a roll-cage of indestructible stiff material like metal and some indestructible panels as inner armor attached to the roll-cage so you prevent shrapnel or indestructible panels to be the cause of death as it bounces around the car.

Body-armor would also be made out of elastic cloth strung out over a frame. Any bullet impacting will have a much longer time over which it is stopped, reducing the concussive damage you will receive. The frame over which it is draped will then take the force. You can make a mechanism where any force pushes the frame inwards, spreading the force over the entire body of the wearer. For example by using an indestructible tube with water inside which is pressurized by any impact. That is assuming you dont let that tube rest on an indestructible frame itself so no amount of force can crush the wearer. That way the only dangers to the wearer are too high acceleration in a direction (say a tank round or truck hits them and accelerates their body away) and any concussive forces that pass throught the frame. By introducing multiple layers of frame+elastics you can absorb and spread lots of the concussive forces before they reach the body itself, although this is no guarantee for safety unless you make that unwieldly thick. Getting hit by a tank shell or truck is still a matter of "don't be there".

Weapons-wise you can create undestructible chambers and barrels, allowing you to overpressure the shots and fire at higher velocities. Although you would probably need to design some kind of partial exoskeleton to bear the increased recoil.

Comment: It is customary to wait 24 hours before accepting an answer. That way people from all over the world have a chance at answering, and if you accept my answer now they might be discouraged from posting their own, which might be a much better answer than mine!